# Convert comma separated string to datetime

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

The Exchange webservice has a method that takes the DateTime in the format below

```
  appointment.Start = new DateTime(2014, 03, 04, 11, 30, 00);
```

I have  a string which is formed by concatenating various fields to form the date my string is as below:

```
   string date="2014,03,04,11,00,00"
```

But if i try to to parse my string as the date it gives the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

```
   DateTime.Parse(date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
string date = "2014,03,04,11,00,00";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. Even though that converts it correctly it seems the Method on this line wants it to be a long ??????appointment.Start = new DateTime(2014, 03, 04, 11, 30, 00);  It says

Comment: The method on which line? Maybe you want the ticks(long), then use `dateTime.Ticks`

Comment: ?appointment.Start = new DateTime(2014, 03, 04, 11, 30, 00);   Error message"?The best overload method match for System.DateTime.DateTime(long) has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it was stressing me out so much i missed the basics

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    string date = "2014,03,04,11,00,00";
    DateTime datDate;
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(date, new string[] { "yyyy,MM,dd,hh,mm,ss" },
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(datDate);
    }
```